# Working around the lack of support for Adaptive Cards 1.2

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

I'm using the AdaptiveCards package (1.2.3) in Bot Framework.
I designed a fancy card and then I saw AdaptiveCards 1.2 is not supported (at least in Azure WebChat and the Emulator).
[image: WebChat message]

There's plenty of useful features in the 1.2 package:

- The `bleed` effect in containers and columns.
- The `ActionSet` feature to display buttons anywhere on the card.
- Being able to `ToggleVisibility` an element.
- ...

Is there any chance that AdaptiveCards 1.2 will be supported anytime soon?

Anyways, I'm trying to work around the problem and get a similar result using the 1.1 version. I tried to simulate the bleed effect with the `padding` property (with no success), I'd also like to have actions in a separate column like so:

[image: Actions in another column]

Is there a way to achieve this in AdaptiveCards 1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to achieve what you want in Adaptive Cards 1.1.

Adaptive Cards 1.2 have been supported in Web Chat for some time. There is a problem with Direct Line that removes certain elements from Adaptive Cards but that should be fixed soon. In the meantime there is a [workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/87#issuecomment-500662897) where you can change the content type to something other than `application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive` and then change it back again on the client side.

Adaptive Cards 1.2 have also been supported in Emulator for some time. Just make sure you have the latest version installed: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases

Comment: Thanks, updated the Bot Framework Emulator and it's kinda working. In the Azure webchat the problem persists tho. Isn't Azure running the latest WebChat version? Also, why the cards are displayed with `"style":"emphasis"` by default in the emulator? Is there a way I can change that or make a container not "emphasis" by explicitly changing its style? (tried with `"style":"default"` but didn't work.

Comment: Again, the problem is Direct Line and not Web Chat, though there's no reason to assume the Azure portal is using the latest version of Web Chat. I don't understand this style problem you're having, so please go ahead and post a new question about that with screenshots.